# Error: Not a valid file name ( OleDbException )

Tags: exception, ado.net, visual-studio-2013, oledbexception

I have a simple Access database, which contains one table. Here is it
[image: Screenshot]

For my Button Load event I have this code

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪E:\addressBook\AddressBook.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    MsgBox("Opened")
    con.Close()
```

And on con.Open() line I am getting this exception . And I can not understand what is the problem. Maybe the name "con" was the problem, but I changed it to "c" or "con1" but the same exception occurs. Can't understand the reason. Thanks for any solution

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Does the file exist at that location? is the file locked? do you have permissions to open the file?

Comment: No it is not locked. And Yes I have all the permissions. And it is located in path that is written in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think *Provider* is required here, as you already have it in the source, change...

```
dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbSource = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪E:\addressBook\AddressBook.mdb"

con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
```

to...

```
dbSource = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪E:\addressBook\AddressBook.mdb"

con.ConnectionString = dbSource
```

Take a look at [*ConnectionStrings*](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

A better solution is to add the file to the `App_Data` folder instead of referencing the file from a local drive.  Add the connection string to the config...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AccessConnection"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|dbName"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The same exception :/

Comment: Yeah. The same exception in my program. Please advice. Here is the connection string @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪‪G:\Edict18042015.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";

Comment: @KushanRandima, instead of placing the file at the route of your *G* drive, consider adding it to the App_Data folder, and adding a connection string in the config - I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

put the `@` before the **connection string**. it works for me!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more as to how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem:
but solution is:
you must give a correct path of your access database, and don't forget the access file name with its extension (your database and .accdb).
I am sure it will be all correct...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\k1.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider
    conn.Open()
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of how this would help users.  But it's not looking like a very helpful answer at the moment...