# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Not a valid file name.'

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I want to display the route names inside in my combo box from a local access database but I get this error and I don't know why. I tried a lot of stuff that I found online but none of them helped.

Maybe there is something wrong with the code?

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        //Connection string:
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪E:\Programming\Job\Jaratok.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT Name FROM Route";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
            }

            connection.Close();
```

[image]

So as you can see, the database is there, in the folder but still...
[image]

Comment: Presuming `File.Exists(@"‪E:\Programming\Job\Jaratok.accdb")` is true, have you tested compiling specifically to 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Please open a command prompt, go to E:\Programming\Job\ and type in `dir`. Then show a screenshot of that (such that we can see the folder name and the file name in the screenshot).

Comment: Not sure if it works. Try to change the platform target to `x86`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Not a valid file name ( OleDbException )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114598/error-not-a-valid-file-name-oledbexception)

Comment: @Zer0 Somewhy File.Exists(@"‪E:\Programming\Job\Jaratok.accdb") returns false but the file is in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=‪E:\Programming\Job\Jaratok.accdb
```

There is a [hidden character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) after the `=` and before the `E:`. You can spot it by putting your cursor to the left of the `=`. Now press right arrow. It moves. Now press it again. **It doesn't move**.

As such, you need to remove that hidden character (i.e. delete the = and E then add them back in).

Comment: what??? it was a hidden character there but how? nice one, thank you very much!